# Who do I turn to for the Terms of Service and Privacy Policy?

Tags: terms-of-use

Are the Terms of Service and Privacy Policy for a web site something I can write up on my own, or do I need to turn to a lawyer or some other professional to do these?

Who are the guys who do the Terms of Service and Privacy Policy for web sites?

How does one go about doing this, and how much does it cost (in the US)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends totally on your bussiness and the actual need of terms etc.

- If what you offer ( information, services or products ) can harm you or your bussiness in any way by misuse of anything you provide, or a human error by yourself make sure you have terms etc.

Again depending on what you offer on your website you could write it yourself , if you feel what you offer could lead to large lawsuits in any way then the cost of a lawyer should not be an issue.

In my experience, most people just copy paste other terms and replace the name. Since you are based in the US you have far mor chance on lawsuits of any kind with your lawsystem.

If you can specify your line of work , website we might be able to give more detailed answers

Answer (score 1):

I usually use http://termsfeed.com/ to generate generic boilerplate PP/ToS and then have a look through some competitors' to see if they have anything special that I might want to add.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Terms of Service and Privacy Policy of competing websites and do something similar.

Going to a lawyer can be very expensive. But if you do, then type them out yourself and have the lawyer go over it rather than get a lawyer to do it from scratch.